# Шаблонизатор Twig

Tags: twig

Возможно ли передать шаблон в переменную? 
Вопрос такой, есть у меня файл `index.twig` 
в нем нужно в зависимость от логики подставлять кусок html с формами. эти формы хранятся в отдельном файле `form.twig`(так как используется в других местах тоже) на данный момент я использую так 
`{% if check %}
{% include 'form.twig' %}
{% endif %}`

Как можно этот файл `form.twig` хранить в переменой и подставлять в нужных местах без `include` а просто `{{ form }}`?

Comment: Явное лучше неявного. Можно попробовать через макрос сделать, но смысла я в этом не вижу

Comment: а смысл? чем include не подходит?